# Tests passing with assertion fails in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, webstorm, chai

I'm trying to run a basic test using mocha/chai/supertest. When I use the command line, I get the info that the test fails, but in WebStorm I get this

[image]

Here's the code for the test

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

const { expect, } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

const generateUser = (email, password, passwordRepeat) => ({ email, password, passwordRepeat, });

describe('Users', () => {
  describe('POST /users/register', () => {
    it('should get an error saying "Password is invalid"', () => {
      request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(generateUser('test@test.tes', 'invalid', 'invalid'))
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(JSON.stringify(res.body)).to.equal(JSON.stringify({
            errors: [
              'Password is invalid',
            ],
            ok: false,
          }));
        });
    });
    it('should get an error saying "Passwords do not match"', () => {
      request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(generateUser('test@test.tes', 'zaq1@WSX', 'invalid2'))
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(JSON.stringify(res.body)).to.equal(JSON.stringify({
            errors: [
              'Passwords do not match',
            ],
            ok: true,
          }));
        });
    });
    it('should get an error saying "Email is invalid"', () => {
      request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(generateUser('test@test.tessada', 'zaq1@WSX', 'zaq1@WSX'))
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(JSON.stringify(res.body)).to.equal(JSON.stringify({
            errors: [
              'Email is invalid',
            ],
            ok: false,
          }));
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Interesting thing is that this only happens it I run the tests on a describe block. So multiple tests at once. If I run just one test I get the error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronous test and you should use the `done` callback provided by [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). Otherwise, your `it()` test finish successfully before the request assertions are even run, which means, without testing anything.

Supertest [suggests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) to use it like this:

```
   // add done parameter below
   it('should get an error saying "Password is invalid"', (done) => {
      request(app)
        .post('/users/register')
        .send(generateUser('test@test.tes', 'invalid', 'invalid'))
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(JSON.stringify(res.body)).to.equal(JSON.stringify({
            errors: [
              'Password is invalid',
            ],
            ok: false,
          }));

          // call done() when test/assertions finished
          done();
        });
    });
```

Of course you should do this for all your asynchronous tests.

Comment: This works. Weird that it works without the done in cli, but not in webstorm.

Comment: Yes this is weird. You can thank Webstorm otherwise you have no clue that a test wasn't testing anything. It happened too me very recently. A small `return` mistake in a test helper, and some tests were just always passing like that...